# App Inventor Error 1113: Unable to build request data

Tags: app-inventor

I'm trying to create an app. I want this app to send some info to a google form in order to fill a sheet in. I saw a really well explained example here:

http://puravidaapps.com/spreadsheet.php

I applied the neccesary changes for my project but an error appears: "`Error 1113: Unable to build request data: element 1 does not contain two elements`". I checked everyhing. The entries are OK, the URL of the form is OK. I still dont know the purpose of the block that calls the "txbmessage": that could be the error(image of the example bellow). Please, compare both designs to realise where the error is.

[My App's blocks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKrIc.png)
[image]

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look carefully at the [mentioned example](https://puravidaapps.com/spreadsheet.php), you will realize, that the `BuildRequestData` method expects a list of lists, and **each sublist has 2 items: a key and a value**. What you created is a list of lists, which has only one sublist with 8 items...

[image]